# Angular 2+ Material stepper : Is it possible to open all steps in material stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to open all steps in the angular material stepper component?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of a stepper divided into logical, ordered steps? You may be able to achieve what you are looking for simply using [Expansion Panels](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) with `multi` set to `true`. For example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwt2tf)

Comment: Yes. Agree. I am trying various options and in that, I would like to have the Material Stepper (all steps) in the open state

Comment: One purpose to expand all is for printing.

Answer (score 15):

For vertical stepper, just add the following in your component's css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-vertical-stepper-content { 
  visibility: visible !important; 
  height: 100% !important; 
}
```

Please note that `ng-deep` is deprecated starting from Angular 8 and it might be removed in future versions.

Comment: Sometimes, to "avoid" use ::ng-deep, you can defined in the styles.css a .css in the way `.custom .mat-vertical-stepper-content{...}` and enclosed you stepper in a div with class `custom`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the style of mat-step-content (using ::ng-deep), you can also create various mat-stepper components.

```
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepContent>
      <p>Step 1 Description</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepContent>
      <p>Step 2 Description</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
.
.
.
```